# Por qué este código lanza un error de sintaxis?

Tags: python

Disculpen tengo el siguiente código:

```
print("\t..MENU--")
print("1.- Ingresar dinero en la cuenta")
print("2.- Retirar dinero de la cuenta")
print("3.- Mostrar dinero disponible")
print("4.- Salir")
opcion = int(input("Digite una opción de menu: "))

if opcion==1:
    extra = float(input("Cuanto dinero desea agregar a la cuenta:"))
    else: extra>205
    print("POr favor ingrese uina cantidad menor a 250")
    elif saldo += extra:
    print(f"Dinero en la cuenta: {saldo}")
```

No sé cuál es el error, soy nueva en la programación, y estoy practicando pero no entiendo por que me da el problema :(

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Las preguntas que contienen el código y/o los errores en una imagen no suelen ser bien recibidas, te aconsejo que copies el código y el error y los pegues en formato texto/código.

Comment: Buenas Andrea es muy, muy recomendable que sigas las indicaciones de @x3k_js .Te dejo la respuesta a lo que creo que necesitas. También te recomiendo que veas tutoriales básicos de python en Youtube o realices algún curso en plataformas como [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) , [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/), etc. Te serán de bastante ayuda

Comment: Copia por favor el código a texto, pues en una imagen es mucho más complicado leer.

Comment: Arregla tu pregunta por favor, el título no dice nada, debería describir tu pregunta. El código debe estar escrito, como imagen sólo nos dificulta ayudarte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Python es un lenguaje que funciona mediante identación, en este caso tu identación es incorrecta.
- El else siempre va al final nunca entre medias.
- Tienes otros errores básicos. (pero sige intentandolo, poco a poco iras mejorando :) )

Intentando comprender tú código creo que lo que necesitas es esto

```
if opcion==1:
    extra = float(input("Cuanto dinero desea agregar a la cuenta: "))
    while extra > 250:
        print('Por favor ingrese una cantidad menor a 250')
        extra = float(input("Cuanto dinero desea agregar a la cuenta: "))
    print("Dinero en la cuenta: {}".format(saldo + extra))
```

como ves en python la identación es fundamental y el conocimiento de los bucles, que es lo que tienes que conocer para este ejercicio, te dejo una explicación del códido

1. El primer **if** es el que selecciona la opción por lo que todo lo que dependa de esa opción (es decir de ese if) debe de ir con un identación
2. Después no necesitas otro if, necesitas un **while**, ya que lo que quieres es que, si el cliente ingresa más de 250€, mandarle un mensaje diciéndole que no es posible, y pidiéndole que ingrese una cantidad menor. Esto se tiene que hacerse las veces que sea necesaria, hasta que el cliente ingrese una cantidad menor a 250. **además como acabamos de iniciar otro bucle while, necesitamos identar lo que vaya dentro de ese bucle**

En resumen `while` se ejecuta indefinidamente hasta que deja de ser True, es decir hasta que el extra introducido es menor de 250.

**Por último** el orden para ejecutar un `ìf` siempre es así:

1. Para iniciar siempre usamos el `if` e identamos todo lo que vaya dentro de esa condición
2. Si hay más de una condición pondríamos a continuación `elif` con la misma identación que el `if` inicial e identamos todo lo que vaya dentro de ese `elif`
3. Para la última condición ponemos un `else` e identamos todo lo que vaya dentro de ese `else`

Te dejo un ejemplo simple:

```
if nota >= 5 and nota < 9:
    nota_texto = 'aprobado'
elif nota >= 9:
    nota_texto = 'sobresaliente'
else:
    nota_texto = 'suspenso'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacer estructuras anidadas de `if-else` en Python se hacen de la siguiente forma:

```
a = 33
b = 33

if b > a:
  print("b es mayor que a")
elif a == b:
  print("a y b son iguales")
elif a > b:
  print("a es mayor que b")
```

Si te das cuenta en tu código tienes un error de sintaxis:

```
if ...
else ... //=> aquí
elif ...
```

Además la expresión `saldo += extra` no tiene sentido ya que el operador `+=` es equivalente a `saldo = saldo + extra` y eso no es un condicional válido.

Lo correcto sería:

```
if opcion == 1:
   ...
elif extra > 250:
   ...
```

A parte de eso, el código que has escrito no tiene mucho sentido ya que la variable `opcion` guarda el modo de funcionamiento que el usuario te introduce por teclado. Una vez entres en la condición correcta para cada modo de funcionamiento ya empiezas a trabajar en base a un contexto, en este caso `ingresar dinero en la cuenta`.

Lo correcto sería:

```
if opcion == 1:
   extra = float(input("Cuánto dinero deseas ingresar?"))
   if extra > 250:
      print("Por favor, ingrese una cantidad inferior...")
   else:
      ...
```